# Using Non-websafe Fonts Causes Jump when Div becomes Visible

Tags: html, css

I use google fonts to show some h1 tag. Initially, this h1 tag is hidden using:

```
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0
```

I then slowly reveal the text when you hover over it with the following:

```
.content:hover{
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity ease-in-out 1s;
}
```

See here for demo: http://codepen.io/gosusheep/pen/oXEyve

Whenever the content becomes fully visible, it jumps a bit.

This jumping **does not** happen when the content is already visible.

This content **does** happen with other non-websafe fonts (e.g. Georgia).

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ueeL0m6j/4/

Comment: Your example also jumps slightly on my machine. I am going to look into Edu Ruiz's solution about removing the transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding a `margin: 20px`, everything works as expected. I was able to keep the transform as well.

What I believe is happening is that the font requires more space than the content div actually has. When opacity reaches 1, the text is fully rendered and goes outside the bounds of the div, causing a small shift.

Comment: wow! that was new to me! but removing the transform worked too, right?

Comment: It did stop the font from jumping, but the font I'm using has little tails at the end of the letters. Those things still jerk into frame and look strange.

Comment: so, will be good if you accept one of the answers so people with the same problem can came here and quick find the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not with the visibility, the problem is the `transform` and `transition` together, try center the content with `top: 50%;` and `margin-top: negative_half_of_the_div_heigh;`.